# Ruby: Display Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following in a view file:

```
<%= render :partial => "medium_deal", :collection => category_locales, :as => :deal_locale %>
```

In my partial template file, I want to print out all attributes for deal_locale. How can I do that? (Basically, a var_dump in PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is just for debugging purposes?  If so

```
<% logger.info "#{deal_locale.inspect}" %>
```

should do the trick.

Or, if you really want to see it in your browser, just

```
<%= "#{deal_locale.inspect}" %>
```